# Thinktecture Identity server v2 token validation

Tags: thinktecture

Is there a way to validate the access_token we got from the identity server v2 ? I know in V3 there is a end point http://*** /core/accessTokenValidation?token=***. How do I do that in V2 ?

Thanks in advance.